# Spring security remember me giving the error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, remember-me

I have recently implemented the `Spring Security Token based remember me` functionality in my `Java Spring MVC web application`. My spring-security.xml fie is as follows:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/layout/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/min/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/v3/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/password/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/register/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/unsubscribe/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false"  />

        <!-- enable csrf protection
        <csrf />
        -->
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <remember-me key="myAppKey" />

    </http>
```

After implementing this feature, the remember me function is working. But I am getting an error as follows:
[image: Error Screen]

I have tried to add the `permitAll()` option to the login `URL' as understood from some docs. But nothing seems to be working for me. The same configuration is working for me in all my other web applications.

Comment: Use your browser's web developer features to figure out what URLs are redirecting to what.  (I suspect that something is redirecting to the wrong place ...)

Comment: Hmmm ... is "/login**" the correct syntax?   If it isn't matching the login page, then the `permitAll()` would not apply and you would drop through to the "/**" rule for the login page (!)

Comment: @Stephen C, I find that / is the URL to which there are too many redirects

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
```

TO

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need permission to a login page:

Outside your `http tag`, add this

```
<http security="none" pattern="/login" />
```

and remove

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />
```

This applies for those cases you wanna load css/js files too

Your file will look like this, for example:

```
    <http security="none" pattern="/login" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/layout/**" />
    <http security="none" pattern="/min/**" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/v3/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/password/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/register/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/unsubscribe/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"/>

            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false"  />

            <!-- enable csrf protection
            <csrf />
            -->
            <!-- access denied page -->
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

            <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
            <remember-me key="myAppKey" />

     </http>
```

Reference Spring Security documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-minimal

**3.2.3 Form and Basic Login Options**

Note that you can still use auto-config. The form-login element just overrides the default settings. Also note that we've added an extra intercept-url element to say that any requests for the login page should be available to anonymous users [5]. Otherwise the request would be matched by the pattern /** and it wouldn't be possible to access the login page itself! **This is a common configuration error and will result in an infinite loop in the application.** Spring Security will emit a warning in the log if your login page appears to be secured. It is also possible to have all requests matching a particular pattern bypass the security filter chain completely, by defining a separate http element for the pattern like this: